# DART: Display Selected Contact

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Dart Programming and programming in general and I was trying to display a contact already picked using the package contact_picker. I am now trying to display the selected contact in the body and I can't seem to get my way around it. I have tried Text(contact) but it doesn't help. (the contact is saved as contact and print(contact) even displays it in the console)

````
            Expanded(
              child: Card(
                borderOnForeground: true,
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
                elevation: 30.0,
                child: Text(
                contact,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38, fontSize: 32),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),```
````

Comment: _It returns the error Contact can't be assigned type string._

Answer (score 0):

Change this code `Text(contact)` to This `Text(contact.toString())`